# How to access the attribute value of soap UI response XML

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I am very new to Groovy & Soap UI

I have response XML as

```
<carrierUDOResponse ReferenceId="" Result="SUCCESS" xmlns:xsi="" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CarrierUDOReponse.xsd
        <errors>
            <error code="0" description="**i WANT TO ACCESS THIS**" property=""/>
        </errors>
        <warnings>
            <warning code="0" description="" property=""/>
        </warnings>
    </errorsAndWarnings>
</carrierUDOResponse>
```

In the Groovy script I want to **capture the value of attribute** and pass it to next step. How should I capture?

The groovy script is below

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "Create_shipment#Response" )
// loop item nodes in response message
for( item in holder.getNodeValues( "//error.code" ))
log.info "errors : [$item]"
def no = holder["count(//error)"]
```

Comment: Are you expecting single value or multiple values? Because, for loop being used.

Comment: I just want values from description, there may the case that it can can have multiple <error> tags

Answer (score 5):

Here is the groovy script that extracts the required description attributes using `xpath`.

Looks like the given xml is partial, and not well formed.

In order to show you the how to extract the data, modified a bit of your xml snippet. But basically idea is same.

- Create the XmlHolder
- Apply the xpath to get the value

```groovy
def xml='''<carrierUDOResponse ReferenceId="" Result="SUCCESS">
        <errorsAndWarnings>
        <errors>
            <error code="0" description="Description for code 0" property=""/>
            <error code="1" description="Description for code1" property=""/>
        </errors>
        <warnings>
            <warning code="0" description="" property=""/>
        </warnings>
    </errorsAndWarnings>
</carrierUDOResponse>'''
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(xml)
//use the xpath to retrieve the desctiption.
def descriptions = holder.getNodeValues("//*:errorsAndWarnings/*:errors/*:error/@description")
//logging the descriptions
descriptions.each{
    log.info "Error: $it"
}
```

Here the variable `descriptions` contains the list of error descriptions.

I am adding below information based on your statement that you wanted to use these descriptions in the following step. But, the information is not completely available how your use case is. Hoping that below would be helpful too.

If you want this data to be available to the next step, the following are possibilities. But it may vary how the data is really needed in the next step. **Also note that here there are list of error descriptions available.**

- **Use it in another groovy script:**
  It is possible to pass data / object from one groovy script step to other groovy step using `context` variable.
  For example you can add the descriptions to context in the above groovy script, so that the same can be retrieved in the following step.
- **Use it in another test request step (soap / rest):** Here you will be able use a string data, but not really list can be used in a simple way.

Comment: only to simplify you can use a shorter *XPath*: `//*:error/@description`. nice response + 1 `:)`

Comment: Thnx Rao, for providing the detailed answer, it really helped me

Comment: The soapui XmlHolder page in API manual: http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/xmlholder.html and getNodeValue method takes an xpath string. xpath spec explained: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp
id = oResponseHolder.getNodeValues("//*:deliverRequest/@id")

Answer (score 2):

@Rao provides the right answer `:)`, only to give and alternative instead of [`XmlHolder`](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/xmlholder.html) you can do the same with a [`XmlSlurper`](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) as follows:

```java
// get the response contenxt
def content = context.expand('${Create_shipment#Response}')
// parse the content
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(content)
// get descriptions
def descriptions =xml.depthFirst().findAll{it.name() == 'error'}*.@description
descriptions.each{
    log.info "description: $it"
}
```