# How to send XML reponse to groovy script in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

Referring to this previous question:
[How to access the attribute value of soap UI response XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053657/how-to-access-the-attribute-value-of-soap-ui-response-xml/43368943#43368943)

I need this script to be dynamic, be able each test run to send a different XML body to parse.
How can this be achieved?

Sample XML

```html
</script>
      <form onsubmit="submitAction();return false;" name="submitForm" method="post" action="auth_vbv_browser_authentication.xsl">
         <input value="auth_vbv_browser_authentication.xsl" type="hidden" name="AA_CurrentPage"/>
         <input value="false" type="hidden" name="TDS_DeviceAuthentication"/>
         <input value="0" type="hidden" name="mobileCount"/>
         <table width="390" height="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" bgcolor="#e8e8e8" align="center">
            <tr>
               <td valign="top">
                  <table width="100%" style="padding:20px;" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                     <tr>
                        <td valign="top" height="1">
                           <img width="140" src="../580655198662148898/auth_issuer_logo_vbv.gif" height="47" border="0" align="left"/>
                           <img width="89" src="../580655198662148898/auth_vbv_lg.gif" height="51" border="0" align="right"/>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td height="20"/>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td height="1" colspan="3" align="right">
                           <font size="-2">
                              <span style="display:none" name="links">
                                 <a onclick="return openDialog(2,1)" id="langLink_sec" href="#">???</a>
                                 <a style="display:none" id="lang_link_sec">???</a>
                                  English
                              </span>
                              <noscript>
                                 <a href="auth_vbv_browser_authentication.xsl?AA_CurrentPage=auth_vbv_browser_authentication.xsl&amp;AA_Ignore_Pattern=true&amp;AA_LANCODE=1&amp;SSID=1710d5e8428fd9d53db2fe7cfb1c79a5af0ecce&amp;popup=false">???</a>
                                  English
                              </noscript>
                           </font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td valign="top" height="1">
                           <font class="auth_Heading_en">Enter Your Authentication Data</font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td height="1"/>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td valign="top" height="1">
                           <font class="auth_TxtMain_en">Please enter your</font>
                           <font class="auth_TxtMain_en">Verified by VISA Password</font>
                           <font class="auth_TxtMain_en">in the field(s) below to verify your identity for this purchase. This information is not disclosed to the merchant.</font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
```

(part of it very long):

I need to get out from this the value of SSID (1710d5e8428fd9d53db2fe7cfb1c79a5af0ecce).

Tried:

```
    def xml = context.response
    def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(xml)
    //use the xpath to retrieve the desctiption.
    def ParRes = holder.getNodeValues("//*:input/@value")
    //logging the descriptions

    def str = new StringBuilder();
    ParRes.each{
        if("$it" != "InitAuth" ){
            str = "$it"
        }
    }

return str
```

Comment: what you posed is not an xml.

Comment: i get this as HTML, but i need to retrieve the parameter from the XML response view, the only place where i can see it.

Comment: maybe there is a way to transfer this property as responseAsXml? but how will i specify what i need?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to handle dynamic response and parse it if [Script Assertion](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html) is used for the same request step where you get the response. Thus an additional groovy script step can be avoided.

All the changed required is to change 1st statement from

```
def xml = """ 
static xml content
"""
```

to

```
def xml = context.response
```

And rest of the solution pointed in your question remains same.

Comment: i am getting:org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: </head> does not close tag <META>.

Comment: and one more thing, the purpose is not assertion. I need to pass some value from the xml to another test step.

Comment: `code`def xml = context.response
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(xml)
def ParRes = holder.getNodeValues("//*:input/@value")

Comment: Please add your sample xml in the question and mention which data needs to be passed to other step?

Comment: now got: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 3): '&'

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided complete response so I took only the form tag:

```
  <form onsubmit="submitAction();return false;" name="submitForm" method="post" action="auth_vbv_browser_authentication.xsl">
     <input value="auth_vbv_browser_authentication.xsl" type="hidden" name="AA_CurrentPage"/>
     <input value="false" type="hidden" name="TDS_DeviceAuthentication"/>
     <input value="0" type="hidden" name="mobileCount"/>
     <table width="390" height="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" bgcolor="#e8e8e8" align="center">
        <tr>
           <td valign="top">
              <table width="100%" style="padding:20px;" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                 <tr>
                    <td valign="top" height="1">
                       <img width="140" src="../580655198662148898/auth_issuer_logo_vbv.gif" height="47" border="0" align="left"/>
                       <img width="89" src="../580655198662148898/auth_vbv_lg.gif" height="51" border="0" align="right"/>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td height="20"/>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td height="1" colspan="3" align="right">
                       <font size="-2">
                          <span style="display:none" name="links">
                             <a onclick="return openDialog(2,1)" id="langLink_sec" href="#">???</a>
                             <a style="display:none" id="lang_link_sec">???</a>
                              English
                          </span>
                          <noscript>
                             <a href="auth_vbv_browser_authentication.xsl?AA_CurrentPage=auth_vbv_browser_authentication.xsl&amp;AA_Ignore_Pattern=true&amp;AA_LANCODE=1&amp;SSID=1710d5e8428fd9d53db2fe7cfb1c79a5af0ecce&amp;popup=false">???</a>
                              English
                          </noscript>
                       </font>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td valign="top" height="1">
                       <font class="auth_Heading_en">Enter Your Authentication Data</font>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td height="1"/>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td valign="top" height="1">
                       <font class="auth_TxtMain_en">Please enter your</font>
                       <font class="auth_TxtMain_en">Verified by VISA Password</font>
                       <font class="auth_TxtMain_en">in the field(s) below to verify your identity for this purchase. This information is not disclosed to the merchant.</font>
                    </td>
                 </tr>

              </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

As per my understanding you want the Value of SSID i.e
**1710d5e8428fd9d53db2fe7cfb1c79a5af0ecce**
and you want to transfer this in next step,so why dont you use **Property transfer** step and provide **Xpath** as below:
substring-before(substring-after(/form[@onsubmit="submitAction();return false;"]/table[@width="390"]/tr/td[@valign="top"]/table[@width="100%"]/tr[3]/td[@height="1"]/font[@size="-2"]/noscript/a[@href="auth_vbv_browser_authentication.xsl?AA_CurrentPage=auth_vbv_browser_authentication.xsl&AA_Ignore_Pattern=true&AA_LANCODE=1&SSID=1710d5e8428fd9d53db2fe7cfb1c79a5af0ecce&popup=false"]/@href,"SSID="),"&")

result of this Xpath:**1710d5e8428fd9d53db2fe7cfb1c79a5af0ecce**
I have tested it on my SOAPUI and working fine.Hope this helps

**Note:** I have copied Xpath from **Form** tag,Please change the Xpath as per your requirement,you can use online tools to calulate Xpath or any XML editor.

For more info on Xpath :[Check this out](http://www.udsayshelloworld.com/2017/03/26/xpath-functions-soapui/)