# How to read an value from Soap request using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

How can I get ******* from User id from the below request using groovy:

```
soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rol="http://www.visa.com/ROLSI">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rol:SIGetBatchQueueRequest>
         <rol:RequestHeader>
            <rol:User id="******" type="internalId"/>
          <rol:MemberRole>A</rol:MemberRole>
         </rol:RequestHeader>
         <rol:RequestData>
            <rol:BatchQueueType>AWAITING_ACTION_BQ_PRE_FILING</rol:BatchQueueType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <rol:PageNum>?</rol:PageNum>
         </rol:RequestData>
      </rol:SIGetBatchQueueRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the attribute value of soap UI response XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053657/how-to-access-the-attribute-value-of-soap-ui-response-xml)

Comment: Have u got output?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [doc](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html). Anyway for your question it will be quick answer,

Try this code :

```
String txt = '''<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rol="http://www.visa.com/ROLSI">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rol:SIGetBatchQueueRequest>
         <rol:RequestHeader>
            <rol:User id="******" type="internalId"/>
          <rol:MemberRole>A</rol:MemberRole>
         </rol:RequestHeader>
         <rol:RequestData>
            <rol:BatchQueueType>AWAITING_ACTION_BQ_PRE_FILING</rol:BatchQueueType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <rol:PageNum>?</rol:PageNum>
         </rol:RequestData>
      </rol:SIGetBatchQueueRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
'''
println new XmlParser().parseText(txt).'soapenv:Body'.'rol:SIGetBatchQueueRequest'.'rol:RequestHeader'.'rol:User'.'@id'
```